# Trying to compile sass/scss file into css files (one to one)

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

We are trying to compile our sass files to css files, however we want to compile each individual sass file into an individual css file (one-to-one).

For example our **product_view.scss** should have a **product_view.css**.

However all configurations we have tried create one css file for everything called **styles.css** in our "out/css" folder.

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            compass: true,
            style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= pkg.src %>/assets/sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '<%= pkg.src %>/assets/media/out/css',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    },

},
```

Comment: If you use the `grunt-contrib-compass` compiler, you can easily do this, my setup for that is: `'default': { options: { sassDir: "css/sass/", cssDir: "css/", outputStyle: "compressed" } }` and it outputs every file as its own (as long as it does not start with a `_`). Compass is SASS, but with even more magic :)

Comment: thanks. i will try that. Do you want to maybe change your comment to an answer?

Comment: Have done. Compass is great, have a look into it - its like extended magic SASS.

Answer (score 1):

I use `grunt-contrib-compass` (Compass) to compile my SASS, which has some nice extras. For example, compass includes a reset utility you can use by using

```
@import 'compass/reset';
```

But disregarding that, compass also outputs every file individually (as long as it does not start with `_` which are files that can be included but won't be compiled by themselves). Here is the setup I use in my gruntfile:

```
compass: {
    'default': {
        options: {
            sassDir: "css/sass/",
            cssDir: "css/",
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the src and destination values set?

Comment: ahhhh sassDir = src, and cssDir = target

Comment: Jup, thats the key! :)

Comment: @OliverWatkins If this worked, could you mark it as correct?

Comment: hmmm for me it keeps crashing. The grunt command "grunt compass" just hangs forever

Comment: I will have to look at it again next week